# td's not lined up against btn-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The text in the `<td>` is not centrally lined up (valign) straight against `btn-group` on the last `<td>`.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/rsf1f6wn/

How to fix this?

```
<table id="myDataTable" class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Orders</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="active">
      <td><a href="#">FirstName Lastame</a></td>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">Add</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `vertical-align: middle` for the below class:

```css
.table thead>tr>th,
.table tbody>tr>th,
.table tfoot>tr>th,
.table thead>tr>td,
.table tbody>tr>td,
.table tfoot>tr>td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This also has a specificity concern. So the above code works to get the correct element targeted in the right specificity.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9x0f7r3c/**